# What orange, stringy fungus might be killing my plants?

Tags: fungus

Last summer all of my plants started dying  I noticed this orange, stringy stuff which I think attacks plants.  They died out during the winter but they are back this Spring.  How do I get rid of them?  I thought it was just in the mulch but it is in the dirt also.

Comment: Need some clarification - first, any chance of a photograph or two, which would be much simpler, but  if not, which plants exactly? And did they die? And are you saying the orange stringy stuff is back, or the plants are back? And that the stringy stuff is on the soil and mulch and on plants? Was the orange stringy stuff on your plants originally?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuscuta  Check this article and please get back to us with pictures...okay?

Comment: Do you have something looking like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Fuligo_septica_bl1.JPG ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this fungus or weed growing in my flower bed?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4030/what-is-this-fungus-or-weed-growing-in-my-flower-bed)

Comment: @J.Chomel The link to your comment which says "Could be this slime mold again" isn't working for me. It opens to a page at Colorado State University, but says the information you're looking for doesn't exist. Could you check it? It could be something on my end. Thanks!

Comment: @Sue, it appears they just remove the picture. Anyway, I removed the link. But I don't get why this question just poped up on top of GL questions... Let's close it.